# Как в exe запаковать картинку

Tags: c++, winapi, exe

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, только через ресурсы это можно сделать или как то еще по другому? Если как по другому можете привести пример?

Comment: Через ресурсы - это универсально и проще, т.к. этот ресурс можно всегда заменить и это не потребует пересборки всего проекта. Что касается простого Bitmap, то его можно и [из буфера в памяти загрузить](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886831/win32-c-c-load-image-from-memory-buffer), а исходную картинку (любой граф. формат) можно всегда представить в виде растра (набора байт в массиве).

Comment: Я битмап отрисовываю побуферу и размеру буфера, а в ресурсах там какая какие то винопишные используются функции отрисовки битмапов, они не подходят мне
Я прочитал ссылки вроде говорят то что надо, а код какой то не такой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую пояснить детально внесение внешнего файла в данные.
Итак, часть 1. Пишем программу, которая читает в бинарном (не текстовом!!) режиме файл, и каждый байт записывает как элемент массива. См., например, [этот код](http://vpaste.net/LQpvw).

Часть 2. Применяем эту программу к внешнему файлу, получаем файл с описанием массива. Типа `unsigned char img[] = { 0x02, 0x15, ...`. Еще лучше - добавить сразу и вторую переменную типа `int img_len = ...`.

Часть 3. Вставляем этот файл в проект. Где надо - обращаемся к этому массиву; например, чтобы записать его опять в файл -

```
FILE * f = fopen("out","wb");
if (f) {
    fwrite(f,img,1,img_len);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Примерно так.

Comment: у меня ошибка в 3 части, содержимое img чем то отличается от содержимого передаваемой ReadFile функции

Comment: Разобрался, я забыл выделить память через VirtualAlloc
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Есть "дедовский" способ. Имея файл картинки, сгенерируйте по нему код объявления массива вида

```
const char a[] = { ... };
```

где ... - данные из файла, конечно, в виде корректно записанных констант. Получите массив, идентичный содержимому файла картинки. Тип массива может быть и другим, в зависимости от того, какой удобнее будет использовать.

Затем просто включите этот файл в проект, используйте массив как внешний. Как вариант, можно поместить в массив не все содержимое файла, например без заголовка и т.п. в зависимости от формата изображения.

Comment: fwrite((void*)fileContent.Contents, fileContent.ContentsSize, 1, fp);
fwrite(&fileContent.ContentsSize, sizeof(fileContent.ContentsSize), 1, fp);
Вот я записал в файл содержимое и размер содержимого и мне его нужно будет записать в const char a[] = { ... };?
И в файл в бинарном виде записывать или в обычном?

Comment: @helldrg Плохо тем, что если это изображение не нужно, то оно все равно будет торчать в памяти. А код - ну, что-то типа http://vpaste.net/LQpvw Замените только на свои имена файлов и массива.

Comment: Насчет того, что они память будут занимать ничего страшного! 
Спасибо большое, и вот на последок:
ReadFile(FileHandle, fileContent.Contents, FileSize32, &BytesRead, 0);
Я этой функцией обычно читаю данные из картинки, если применить к данному случаю:
fileContent.Contents это тоже самое что и массив символов
FileSize32 это количество байтов, которое занимает массив символов?

Comment: @Harry fileContent.ContentsSize = sizeof(img_background)-1;
 memcpy((void*)fileContent.Contents, &img_background, fileContent.ContentsSize); 
Я так пробую записать - не получается

Comment: @helldrg Выложите где-нибудь полный исходник, так непонятно. И еще - а чем мой вариант не устроил, почему только через API, а не стандартными С'шными функциями?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pQ40YKhT
Я ваш вариант и использую, у вас только нет концовки, т.е. вывода картинки из переменной на экран, я пробую вывести, у меня ошибка в мемсру появляется

Comment: @helldrg Что такое у вас `img_background`? Вы записали картинку в массив `zero` - но я не вижу его использования...

Comment: уже не zero, я переименовал в ручную переменную =)